# Multiple recipients with one shopping cart

Tags: php, paypal

I have one (custom PHP) shopping cart, with multiple products.

I am already using Encrypted Website Payments, to encrypt the final buy now button on the fly.

Some items in the cart may be owned by myself, and some by my partner.

So far, I've just been accepting all the funds into my own PayPal account, and redistributing the ones needed to him, but I'd rather have payments for him, go directly to him. (mostly so they don't show up on my own 1099 statements)

Can I split the payment between multiple vendors?  Getting API access granted from the other account would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/). It allows for payments to be sent to two parties.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to locate.  I was pretty sure there was a method.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) and [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) support parallel payments.

HowTo's:

- [How to Make Parallel Payments Using Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/)
- [How to Make a Parallel Payment Using Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/)